# Issue with SQL Server query

Tags: sql-server

In the below query I have select loadingcost and unloadingcost and freight charge from otherexpensecost table. But I want to check that for a goodsreceivednoteid count is more than 1 in GoodsReceivedNoteDetails Table it should get from  GoodsReceivedNoteDetailtable else the loading and unloading charge and freight charge it should get from otherexpensecost table. But in the below query I get loading cost, unloading, freight charge from otherexpense cost table without check the no of GoodsReceivedNoteID in GoodsReceivedNoteDetail.

Table 1 Other expenseCost:

```
GoodsReceivedNoteID
LoadingCost
UnloadingCost
FreightCharges
```

Table2  GoodsReceivedNoteDetail

```
GoodsReceivedNoteID
GoodsreceivedNoteDetailID
ProductID
LoadingCost
UnloadingCost
FreightCharges
```

Query:

```
SELECT      
    GRN.GoodsReceivedNoteNo,
    GRN.LocationID,
    GRN.CreatedOn,
    PO.PurchaseOrderNo,
    V.VendorName,
    GRN.SupplierInvoiceNo,
    GRN.SupplierInvoiceDate,
    SR.LRNO,
    T.TransporterName,
    ISNULL((OEC.FreightCharges), 0.00) FreightCharge,
    ISNULL((OEC.LoadingCost+OEC.UnloadingCost), 0.00) LoadingandUnloadingcharges,
    P.ProductCode,
    P.ProductName,
    GRND.ReceivedQuantity,
    GRND.RejectedQuantity,
    GRND.AcceptedQuantity,
    GRND.UnitPrice AS BasicRate,
    ISNULL((GRND.UnitPrice * GRND.ReceivedQuantity), 0.00) BasicValue,
    GRND.VAT,
    ISNULL((OEC.FreightCharges), 0.00) AS FreightApporitioned,
    ISNULL((OEC.LoadingCost + OEC.UnloadingCost), 0.00) AS LoadingandUnloadingApportioned,
    ISNULL((GRND.UnitPrice + OEC.FreightCharges + OEC.LoadingCost + OEC.UnloadingCost), 0.00) AS TotalCost
FROM 
    GoodsReceivedNoteDetail GRND
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    GoodsReceivedNote GRN ON GRN.GoodsReceivedNoteID = GRND.GoodsReceivedNoteID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    PurchaseOrder PO ON PO.PurchaseOrderID = GRN.PurchaseOrderID
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    Vendor V ON V.VendorID = PO.VendorID
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    SecurityRegister SR ON SR.SecurityRegisterID = GRN.SecurityRegisterID
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    Transporter T ON T.TransporterID = SR.TransporterID
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    OtherExpenseCost OEC ON OEC.GoodsReceivedNoteID = GRN.GoodsReceivedNoteID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    Product P ON P.ProductID = GRND.ProductID
WHERE 
   GRND.CreatedOn >= @d_StartDate 
   AND  GRN.LocationID = @i_LocationID 
   AND GRND.CreatedOn <= @d_EndDate 
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `window function` to find the `count` of each `GoodsReceivedNoteID`. Try something like this.

```
Select
......
CASE
    WHEN Count(GRND.GoodsReceivedNoteID) OVER(partition BY GRND.GoodsReceivedNoteID) > 1 
    THEN Isnull(( GRND.FreightCharges ), 0.00)
    ELSE Isnull(( OEC.FreightCharges ), 0.00)
END FreightCharge,
CASE
    WHEN Count(GRND.GoodsReceivedNoteID) OVER(partition BY GRND.GoodsReceivedNoteID) > 1 
    THEN Isnull(( GRND.LoadingCost + GRND.UnloadingCost ), 0.00)
    ELSE Isnull(( OEC.LoadingCost + OEC.UnloadingCost ), 0.00)
END LoadingandUnloadingcharges 
.....
```